# Nvidia-smi no devices were found in VMWare Ubuntu 20.04.03 and RTX3060

Tags: drivers, nvidia, vmware, cuda, gpu-driver

I tried to install CUDA 11.6 on my Ubuntu 20.04.03 which is running on VMWare esxi based on the tutorial here : https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#ubuntu-installation. I wanted to use GPUDirect Storage so before that, I installed MLNX_OFED as mentioned here: [https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#install-mlnx-ofed because](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#install-mlnx-ofed). But when I issue the command `nvidia-smi`, I keep getting `no devices were found`. At first my linux kernel was 5.13, but after getting no results, I downgraded it to 5.4 because the Nvidia documentation said this version is tested and reinstalled the cuda afterwards. I even changed the Nvidia driver to version 470 in “additional drivers” but still getting “no devices were found”. I asked the network admin and she said the driver is installed on the machine that VM is running on.
can please anybody help?

Comment: The GPU passtrough isn't working, perhaps?

Comment: @ChanganAuto I couldn't fix the problem and decided to use a real machine instead of a VM and now it's working flawlessly

Comment: If you don't have two GPUs and used GPU passtrough to the VM then, of course, there was nothing to fix.